# Stack Float the TextView in Left and Right

Tags: android, android-layout

Is this the correct way to place the TextView in left and right side of the view?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/l_section_login"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_forgot_password"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:text="Forgot Password?" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_sign_up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
        android:text="Sign up?"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have hardcoded `180dp` as a margin. This won't handle devices with different screen sizes gracefully.

I'd recommend starting with a ConstraintLayout and using `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` in the second TextView

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Left"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Right"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use a linear layout you can fill the line with empty views and use weights,for example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:text="Forgot Password?"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="Sign up?" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```